# CSS transition between "height:50px" and "height:auto"

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a DIV with a default fixed height and an `overflow:hidden` property to hide content that is to broad to be contained inside it.

```
div
{
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

I would like to autoexpand this DIV hovering it with mouse but I have the problem that **CSS transition works only with a fixed height and not with an auto height**.

Here a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x09698qt/) that illustrate two cases.

I know that reason is that for some reason browrse does not know "*how many px are auto height*" but is there exist a workaround (maybe using `max-height` property...) to avoid need of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

When you give `height: auto` in the animation, it doesn't know what to do. As it cannot calculate the `height` on the fly. So, initialize the height using jQuery this way:

```
$(function () {
  $(".auto_height").each(function () {
    $(this).data("height", $(this).height());
  });
});
```

And in CSS, give:

```
height: attr(data-height);
```

Comment: Thank you, even if I asked for a solution WO jQuery. Anyway, is an interesting solution, I have thought about adding "height:XX px" as an inline style, rather than populating a data-attribute. Can you explain me why using this instead an inline style should be better?

Comment: That's what I said. What you are doing is an interactive event, should be handled only by event managing script, which is JavaScript.

Comment: No, I wanted to say.... I understood why you use jQuery to calculate the height, buy I don't have clear why assigning it to a data-attribute instead as inline style `$(this).css("height", $(this).height());`

Comment: Well, I am not sure why I used it, but it works. LoL...